# How to enable OpenType font features for Hangul?

Tags: xetex, cjk, opentype, xecjk

In my document, I need to typeset some Hangul syllables that are not available as composite characters. I tried to set this up as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Script=Hangul,Language=Korean]{Source Han Sans KR}

\begin{document}
가
\end{document}
```

The text is typeset in the correct font but as separate Jamo, not a composed syllable. Using `\fontspec` as in the example below works, but requires me to mark which text is Hangul manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Script=Hangul,Language=Korean]{Source Han Sans KR}
가
\end{document}
```

The `xeCJK` documentation is less than helpful, being written in Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=159) and had been fixed in `xeCJK` [revision 737](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/source/detail?r=737).

Make sure you are using `xeCJK` version `2014/11/10 v3.2.15` or later.
Update your packages when necessary.

Sorry for the Chinese only document (again).

BTW, for those who cannot compile the test document, see [Korean characters scrambled [XeLaTeX; Noto Sans Korean]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191931/korean-characters-scrambled-xelatex-noto-sans-korean)